# Reading Regex patterns from an XML file

Tags: c#, regex, xml

I have an XML file that contains a large number of regex search patterns:

```
<Data>
  <Expression>Error removing log\.  Error: 5</Expression>
</Data>
<Data>
  <Expression>Unable to open file C:\\Documents\\Stuff\\Message\.txt</Expression>
</Data>
```

As you can see, the expressions have already been escaped correctly in my XML file. The problem is, when I deserialize the file into a list of strings and then attempt to use the strings as regex patterns, I notice they have been escaped again. For example, the first expression above is being read as:

```
"Error removing log\\.  Error: 5"
```

That pattern then fails to find any matches in the file I'm searching through.

Is there a way to read these expressions from the XML file without them being escaped again?

Changing the way the patterns are written in the XML file is not an option, because I do not have control of the file.

EDIT:
Here is the code that I am using these regex patterns in:

```
    private void FindExpression(Data errorExpression)
    {
        Regex regex = new Regex(errorExpression.Expression,
                                RegexOptions.IgnoreCase,
                                TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2));
        MatchCollection errorMatches = regex.Matches(FileContents);
        // There is more stuff here, to handle if I find a match
    }
```

Comment: They aren't, that is just how they show up in the debugger.

Comment: But I am using the pattern to search, and it is not finding any matches despite the fact that I can see in the file I'm searching that there are matches...

Comment: There's definitely double spaces in the log, right?

Comment: Are these really regular expressions? They are messages. Why are you escaping metacharacters ? Just use a string search function.

Comment: You say that they are 'Regex search patterns'... but in your expressions I see nothing that suggests that they are Regex. Show us the code where you "attempt to use the strings as regex patterns"... I think your error probably lies there.

Comment: Spender - there definitely is a double space in the log.

Sln - these are regular expressions. The ones I show happen to be very simple, but they are not all like that. Most have wildcards and other regex patterns.

Comment: If your looking at them in debugger then they will show as escaped strings. I would guess that the problem is more in the regular expressions or the code you use to run them. Can you put up some of that?

Comment: If a debugger shows you this `"Error removing log\\.  Error: 5"`, then it applied double quote rules to it. Applying it in reverse its `Error removing log\.  Error: 5`

Comment: I am very willing to believe that it's just the debugger showing them as escaped, so it's quite possible my issue lies elsewhere. The file I am using these patterns to search through is large, so I decided to create a test file that is just a subset of that one. My test file contains the lines I know match, and a few others - everything else has been deleted from the file. And now my same code is finding a match. Why would it find a match in a small file, but not the large file, when the lines that should be matched are exactly the same?

Comment: The matches aren't timing out are they? And filecontents has the correct data? Try creating a simple test file that has just one simple regex like .* and just assign a single character to file contents, does that work?

Comment: Try this on your big file `Match _m = regex.Match(strSrc); while (_m.Success){/** examine match **/_m = _m.NextMatch();}`

Comment: When I am debugging through this, it is definitely not taking 2 minutes. After a few seconds it thinks there is no match. But it finds matches in my test file no problem.

Comment: @sln I tried that and I get the same results. It immediately thinks there are no matches on the big file, but it finds matches on the subset of that file.

Comment: Resaving the file hasn't changed encoding on it and accidentally fixed some weird reading issue?

Comment: Then you have to examine the `regex` object in the debugger. Copy the regex string to Word or something or examine the encoding. The encoding of the regex should be the same as the source text.

Comment: @kmcc049, that's a good point, I will check that out when I get back to work tomorrow. Sln, how can I tell what the encoding is?

Comment: I think I found the issue. The encoding on the file I'm searching was causing issues. The documentation on [StreamReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (the class I'm using to read in the file I'm searching), says it defaults to UTF-8, which "handles Unicode characters correctly". Since my file is unicode I didn't bother specifying the encoding. But once I did specify Encoding.Unicode in my StreamReader, everything worked. @Sln, your while loop got me into an infinite loop somehow, though.

Comment: Great! Can I get a point for my guess :P

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did and I dont see the expressions being escaped again.

```
XmlDocument doc1 = new XmlDocument();
doc1.LoadXml(@"<Exps><Data>  <Expression>Error removing log\.  Error: 5</Expression></Data><Data>  <Expression>Unable to open file C:\\Documents\\Stuff\\Message\.txt</Expression></Data></Exps>");
XmlNodeList xmList = doc1.SelectNodes("/Exps/Data/Expression");
foreach (XmlNode node in xmList)
{
    Regex reg = new Regex(node.InnerText);
}
```